# how to resize a button programmatically in a fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, imagebutton

I'm struggling to resize 2 buttons in my fragment which I created in the java file.

My Code:

```
protected Option[] options = {
        //new Option(),
        new Option(R.drawable.male_transparent, R.drawable.male_blue, "male"),
        new Option(R.drawable.female_transparent, R.drawable.female_blue, "female")

};

protected Context context;

protected PrefManager prefManager;

public Question question;

private boolean isAnswered = false;

public Question1Fragment(){
    question = new Question(1, "gender");
}


@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
    prefManager = new PrefManager(context);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutSrc, container, false);

    
}
```

I'm not sure if the resizing is defined in OnCreate method?